# Configure QUIC and HTTP/3 in Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, openssl, quic, http3

I want to install and configure nginx-1.19.0 with HTTP/3 support on Ubuntu 22.04. OpenSSL version is 3.0.2. I was surfing in internet but I didn't find something straight forward to guide me how to implement QUIC and HTTP/3 on server.

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/quic.html Support for QUIC and HTTP/3 protocols is available since **1.25.0**

Comment: Now that the release has a name I can link to the [nginx version in Ubuntu 24.04 (currently not yet 1.25, planned to be released in april 2024)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/nginx)